# How to use WeChat URL Schemes on iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, url-scheme, wechat

I'm trying to get an iOS app to open WeChat to a specific official account page.

I noticed here http://spacekid.me/weixin-url-schemes/ and here https://www.quora.com/Does-WeChat-support-posting-text-to-chat-via-a-url-scheme-for-mobile that there are a number of unofficial URL schemes supposedly supported by WeChat.  I was able to get one of these to work (although the site says that one is disabled...)

```
let url = NSURL(string:"weixin://scanqrcode")!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

This opens up the screen to scan a QR code.

I wasn't able to get any of the URLs listed on that page to work, though.  Clicking on the links in a page in Safari on iOS prompts me to open the WeChat app, but I get the message "Sorry, this page is not available." in WeChat.  I get the same result from my iOS app.

I was wondering if this functionality is only available for Chinese users of the WeChat app, or if I'm doing something wrong here.  This article http://chinachannel.co/wechat-weixin-are-not-the-same/ suggests that WeChat has different functionality depending on whether the user has a Chinese phone number, so I was wondering if that might have something to do with it.

Comment: Did You find Any solution , if , Please share !

Comment: No solution; our conclusion was that these aren't available; at least in the US version of the WeChat SDK...  It seems that it has very limited functionality.  Also it seems that WeChat added and quickly removed a bunch of extra functionality at some point, because it was being used to scam people, but that's just hearsay...

Comment: Well, the scan qr code url started working again. It's not wechat's fault. Apple had some new regulations, trying to cut off a piece of cake from WeChat's functionalities such as payment, etc. WeChat's payment partially depends on qr code scanning, that's why it stopped working for a while. Recently wechat had some negotiation with Apple, and this started to work again...